# How to convert HSL color into HSV color in python (no external library)?

Tags: python

How to convert hsl color into hsv color without any external library in python?

```py
def HEX2HSV(hex):
    hv=HEX2HSL(hex)  # this function return converted HSL value of Hex color code {'h': 300, 's': 67.0, 'l': 80.0}
    # how to convert HSL in to HSV in python without external library?

convertedhsv = HEX2HSV('#eeaaee') # {'h':300,'s':67.0,'l':80.0}
```

hue in HSL and HSV are same but saturation are different and light and value are also different so how can I convert saturation and light of HSL into saturation and value of HSV in python?

Comment: By the way develop a nice skill to simply google something like `hsl to hsv formula` first

Answer (score 1):

Use python std `colorsys` as `HSL -> RGB -> HSV`:

```py
import colorsys
c = {'h': 300, 's': 67.0, 'l': 80.0}
r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(c["h"], c["l"], c["s"])
h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
```

Resu

Comment: I want to know what is the formula and how does conversion works

Answer (score 0):

Try using python's builtin `colorsys` module
like this:

```
import colorsys
def HSL2HSV(h,s,l):
   rgb=colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h,l,s)
   hsv=colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*rgb)
   return hsv
```

Comment: but I want to know how does this conversion works.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Hue_and_chroma

Comment: You can see the colorsys  methods source on  https://gist.github.com/jenca-adam/de249c154d6b349dfa2eef10623d4820

Comment: I have seen some other external library source code and I didn't understood.

Comment: It is not _external_ library.

Comment: I know but I want to know the process to convert light into value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236905/discussion-between-experi-ment-and-adam-jenca).